# Set checkbox disabled if already opted by user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I designed a seat layout with checkbox code looks something like this

```
        <div class="asiento">
          <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="asiento1" name="check" >
          <label for="asiento1">1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="asiento">
          <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="asiento2" name="check" />
          <label for="asiento2">2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="asiento">
          <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="asiento3" name="check" />
          <label for="asiento3">3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="asiento">
          <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="asiento4" name="check" />
          <label for="asiento4">4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="asiento">
          <input type="checkbox" value="5" id="asiento5" name="check" />
          <label for="asiento5">5</label>
        </div>
```

I tried to fetch data from Database using loop and i am getting output like this

```
['1', '2'] ['5']
```

can i do something to remove [ ]  maybe use JQuery or JS to disable the checkbox that are already selected by other users, this is the loop that i used to get value

```
      {% for seat in seat %}
         {{seat.useat}}
      {% endfor %}
```

Django modal.py

```
class Bookings(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
shows = models.ForeignKey(Shows, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
useat = models.CharField(max_length=100)
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username +" | "+ self.shows.movie.movie_name +" | "+ self.useat
```

views.py

```
def booked(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.user
    seat = request.POST.getlist('check')
    show = request.POST['show']
    book = Bookings(useat=seat, shows_id=show, user=user)
    book.save()
    return render(request,"booked.html")
```

Comment: How does your `seat` Django model look like? What fields does it have?

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently saving a python list of seat numbers as a string in the `useat` field, which kinda make the data unusable.

Perhaps something like this will work:

```py
class Bookings(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def useat_as_list(self):
        return self.useat.split(',')
```

```py
def booked(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        seat = ','.join(request.POST.getlist('check'))
        ...
```

```html
<div class="asiento">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="asiento1" name="check" {% if '1' in seat.useat_as_list %}disabled{% endif %}>
    <label for="asiento1">1</label>
</div>
```